# BIRT report: Oracle query: How can I get the output in single row for one Personid

Tags: sql, oracle, birt

Table: LABORCRAFTRATE: It has two cloumns

```
LABORCODE CRAFT
--------- ---------
SP51894   Replace
SP51894   Repair
SP51894   Connect
SP51894   MET1
```

Table: PERSON:  5 columns

```
PERSONID LOCATION STATUS FIRSTNAME LASTNAME
-------- -------- ------ --------- ---------
SP51894  Delhi    ACTIVE Smita     Patil
```

Required Output: 7 Coulmns

```
PERSONID LOCATION STATUS FIRSTNAME LASTNAME Connection Replacement
-------- -------- ------ --------- -------- ---------- ------------
SP51894  Delhi    ACTIVE Smita     Patil    Yes        Yes
```

My query:

```
select distinct
       person.personid, person.location, person.status, person.firstname, person.lastname,
       case when (laborcraftrate.craft = 'CONNECT') then 'Yes' else null end as connection,
       case when (laborcraftrate.craft = 'REPLACE') then 'Yes' else null end as replacement  
from   maximo.person, maximo.laborcraftrate 
where  ((person.personid like '%PM02056%'))
and    person.personid= laborcraftrate.laborcode and person.status in ('ACTIVE','INACTIVE')
and    laborcraftrate.craft in ('CONNECT','REPLACE')
group by person.personid, person.location, person.status, person.firstname, person.lastname, laborcraftrate.craft;
```

This query returns two rows:

```
PERSONID LOCATION STATUS FIRSTNAME LASTNAME Connection Replacement
-------- -------- ------ --------- -------- ---------- ------------
SP51894  Delhi    ACTIVE Smita     Patil    Yes        
SP51894  Delhi    ACTIVE Smita     Patil                Yes
```

How can I get the output in single row for one Personid? 
Distinct is not working in BIRT.. :(

Comment: this article might be helpful http://birtworld.blogspot.com/2010/10/birt-duplicate-rows.html

Comment: By the way, only the brackets around `in` expressions are needed. The rest are not doing anything.

Comment: Apart from solution proposed Barbaros Özhan, another one could be to adjust yours one and have subquery on the laborcraftrate table in the CASE instead of joining the two tables

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Aggregation is needed. You can Apply Aggregation while returning `Connection` and `Replacement` columns along with

```
 GROUP BY PERSON.PERSONID, PERSON.LOCATION, PERSON.STATUS,PERSON.FIRSTNAME, PERSON.LASTNAME
```

Clause :

```
SELECT P.PERSONID, P.LOCATION, P.STATUS, P.FIRSTNAME, P.LASTNAME,
       MAX(CASE
           WHEN (UPPER(L.CRAFT) = 'CONNECT') THEN
               'Yes'
           ELSE
                NULL
           END ) AS Connection,
       MAX(CASE
           WHEN (UPPER(L.CRAFT) = 'REPLACE') THEN
               'Yes'
           ELSE
                NULL
           END ) AS Replacement
  FROM maximo.PERSON P
  JOIN maximo.LABORCRAFTRATE L ON P.PERSONID = L.LABORCODE
 WHERE ((P.PERSONID LIKE '%SP51894%'))
   AND P.STATUS IN ('ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE')
   AND UPPER(L.CRAFT) IN ('CONNECT', 'REPLACE')
 GROUP BY P.PERSONID, P.LOCATION, P.STATUS, P.FIRSTNAME, P.LASTNAME;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=03adc90b5757b835cf9c91fb98e28cbb)</kbd>

Comment: one more question, if PERSONID does not exist in Database then also PERSONID column should get display that ID in output with other column value blank.

Comment: you're welcome @Sonali , excuse me but I couldn't get your question.

Comment: If my understanding is correct - the requirement is to always have 1 record in the output, even if there's no such person in the database. It could be done with some ugly hacks (unions etc). Do not know if there are any good ones

Comment: Say PersonId SP51894 does not exists in database. Then in output result it should show
PERSONID LOCATION STATUS FIRSTNAME LASTNAME Connection Replacement
-------- -------- ------ --------- -------- ---------- ------------
SP51894

Comment: What do you mean by database?  For `PERSON.PERSONID` or `LABORCRAFTRATE.LABORCODE` or both not exist  @Sonali?  And Why `SP51894` does should return ?

Comment: The output should return ‘no matches’ for PERSONID unmatched